Voltage input low of nmos inverter with enhancement load
I have the following schematic in LTSPICE

For each of these circuits I have to find the values for the VOH, VOL, VIL and VIH. To find the input voltages I observe the derivative of the V_out_NMOS voltage and check where it is equal to -1.
In the NMOS inverter with the enhancement load I get this graph

How can I find the VIL ?

According to this textbook chapter, they use the -1 slope where the 2nd derivative is positive, which would be here:


To determine VIH, it is necessary to determine the input level where
the transfer characteristic has a slope of -1 in the vicinity of a
logic low level.  This is easy to do with the aid of the derivative
procedure command available in PROBE. Taking the derivative of the
output voltage (VO) with respect to the input voltage (VI) for the
above two cases and plotting it versus the input voltage level, we
obtain the graphical results shown in Fig. 13.4. From this we see that
the input level in the vicinity of a logic low level corresponding to
a slope of -1 is 1.78 V.  Thus, VIH=1.78 V.  Therefore, the two noise
margins for the enhancement-load inverter with body effect included
are:

Regardless, I think you need to ignore that first noisy section which is due to numerical noise.  You can choose to get rid of it by decreasing the reltol option to 0.0001.

